# Sending ALL logs generated by Mac OS 10.6 to a syslog server?

Tags: macos

I understand it SHOULD work by adding asterisk . asterisk @ip:port. This works with my graylog2 setup...somewhat. Not every log generated and view-able in console shows up in graylog2. Any ideas?

Only some basic messages are showing up, I want everything. Apache, secure.log, etc. Even spelling this out specifically in my config is not helping.

I've been successful in sending every log available on 10.8 and 10.9 machines to graylog2, that works great. I understand it's a different method than 10.6 implements.

Comment: I do not know about mac, but you need a separate parser to log apache and any third party app besides the system logs.... nxlog for example http://nxlog.org/features

Answer (score 1):

The syslog daemon can only send log entries that are submitted to it via the syslog or Apple System Log (asl) APIs. But many programs simply write directly into text files that happen to have ".log" extensions -- since the syslog daemon never sees these "log messages", it never gets the opportunity to send them to a log server.

A few programs can be configured to log via syslog (rather than writing directly to a file). Apache is a good example: normally it writes directly to file, but it has a [syslog module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_syslog.html) that can be [configured to use syslog instead](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/sysadmin/2006/10/12/httpd-syslog.html).

Other programs... you'll have to investigate on a case-by-case basis. Unfortunately, in many cases the answer is going to be that the program just wasn't written to use syslog, so you won't be able to centralize its logs via syslog (at lest, without rewriting the program in question).

Answer (score 0):

Use a log collector like [Fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/) (Mac package maintained by sponsored parent of Fluentd [Treasure Data](http://www.treasuredata.com/))

You can easily install the Treasure Agent with brew and cask:

> brew cask install td-agent

Then follow the [documentation](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/quickstart) for configuring the agent to send the logs you're interested in forwarding.